# Simple program leads to seg fault when opening a file

Tags: c, file, printing, segmentation-fault, arguments

I've got a text file that contains a bunch of strings, nothing important in terms of my problem.

The code here compiles/runs, and If I type in the correct text file, the first if statement runs. However, if I don't the else statement doesn't execute, but instead I get a seg fault, would Mallocing the pointer be of any help here? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

    FILE * ptr;

    if(strcmp(argv[1],"test.txt") == 0)
    {
        printf("Right text file was inputted");
    }
   //but if I wan't the alternative (if the user didn't enter the right thing

    else
    {
     // this never executes, but instead the program just seg faults if the first if statement is not true
     printf("You didn't enter the right textfile, or none at all");
     exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't access `ptr` at all.

Comment: "you don't" means you don't type in any file name as parameter or just typed in an incorrect file name? I guess you did not type in any file name, so at this, the index out of range issue occurred. You should firstly check argc and then argv

Comment: this code does not cleanly compile for (at least) two reasons.  1) the passed parameter 'argc' is not used.  2) this function is declared to return an int, but doesn't actually do so.  (it needs 'return(0);' just before the final closing '}'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `argc` (the count of the number of arguments given) to determine if a value is entered or not. As it stands, accessing `argv[1]` when `argc` is `0`, will cause a segmentation fault <s>as you're accessing passed the end of the array</s> when `strcmp` dereferences the terminating `NULL` pointer.

Your first `if` statement should be:

```
if(argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1],"test.txt") == 0) {
...
```

Comment: actually that is not quite true.  the argv[] array always has a final NULL pointer entry.  The actual problem is trying to de-reference that NULL pointer to compare to 'test.txt'.  The fix, as you stated, is to check argc to be >1, to assure there is a valid value to check against.

Comment: @user362949 thanks, updated my answer. It's been a while since I've done any C programming.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass arguments to main(), they are passes in the form of strings to main(). argc is a count of the arguments passed to the main() and argv is argument vector which is always NULL ended. so if you dont provide any arguments you have to first check with argc count and then proceed. other thing is you cannot check if wrong file name is passed or file name is not passed at all in just one condition

it should be like,

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE * ptr;
    if(argc>1)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[1],"test.txt") == 0)
        {
            printf("Right text file was inputted");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You didn't enter the right textfile");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("you havn't entered any file name");
}
```